# why my application flashes? can't open it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I can't open my app, it always flashBack when I try to open it!

Here is the DDMS information:

```
[2017-02-27 10:33:32 - ddmlib] The software in your host has stopped an    established connection.
java.io.IOException: The software in your host has stopped an established  connection.
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:684)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:523)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:564)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:539)
at  com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:501)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:397)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:64)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$1.run(DeviceMonitor.java:320)
```

Can you tell me what the information means?

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide some code by replacing "enter code here"

Comment: is it emulator or real device ? if real device restart it once and try again.

Comment: Can you provide some like manifest.xml and launching activity code?